# jquery multiple id selectors through php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Html code**

jquery multiple id selectors through php  only one id (qid) working fine

```
<a class="clinks" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" 
     id="msgr<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" href="javascript:void(0)">message</a>
<div id="chatbox<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" ></div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$("#msgr").click(function(){
    $("#chatbox"+qid).fadeIn();
});
```

please explain whats wrong with my code I have tried many ways but not working please help me out with this.

Comment: `$("#msgr")` doesn't exist?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar duplicate means? i have lots of queries with ids that means qid

Comment: @Manav see my code again!

Comment: Your link's `id` is *not* "#msg", it's "#msg123" (or whatever `$d['qid']` is).  Enter this in your console `console.log($("#msg").length)`

Comment: You have an id msgr followed by a string so your id, for example, becomes "msgrstring" and you can no longer use `$("#msgr")` selector

Comment: @MunnaVMC see my answer below

Comment: Learn how to use [Chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or [Firefox dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) to see how your HTML actually looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead id ,change in html

```
<a class="clinks msgr" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" id="msgr_<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" href="javascript:void(0)">message</a>
<div id="chatbox_<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" > </div>
```

And in JS

```
$(".msgr").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
    $("#chatbox_"+id).fadeIn();
});
```

Added an example

```js
$(".msgr").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
    $("#chatbox_"+id).fadeToggle();
    console.log("chatbox_"+id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a class="clinks msgr" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" id="msgr_1" href="javascript:void(0)">message</a>
<div id="chatbox_1" >test1</div>
</div>
<div>
<a class="clinks msgr" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" id="msgr_2" href="javascript:void(0)">message</a>
<div id="chatbox_2" >test2</div>
</div>
<div>
<a class="clinks msgr" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" id="msgr_3" href="javascript:void(0)">message</a>
<div id="chatbox_3">test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: user2486 Thank you so much friend this working

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can manage dynamic id's in jquery

Change

`id="msgr<?php echo $d['qid'];?>`

to

```
<a class="clinks" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" 
     id="msgr_<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" href="javascript:void(0)">message</a>
```

Then you can get the clicked message by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $('[id^="msgr_"]').on('click',function(){
         var index = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
         $("#chatbox"+index).fadeIn();
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use id start with selector here. To target relevant chatbox, you can replace the static part from id(i.e. msgr) to get qid:

```
$("[id^=msgr]").click(function(){
    var currentQid = this.id.replace("msgr","")
    $("#chatbox" + currentQid ).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: No not getting results

Comment: You can do console.log for $("[id^=msgr]").length before click event.you should get the count equal to elements count

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution for your problem

> Please changes your view file

```
<a class="clinks" data-chat-id="<?php echo $d['qid']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" id="msgr" href="javascript:void(0);">
    message
</a>
<div id="chatbox_<?php echo $d['qid']; ?>" style="display:none;"> Test</div>
```

> Please change your script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.clinks', function () {
        var chatbox_id = $(this).attr('data-chat-id');
        $("#chatbox_" + chatbox_id).fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $("#chatbox_" + chatbox_id).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This will open all the links with that class on click

Comment: @ NikuNj Rathod
 no Not working

Comment: @MunnaVMC Please check now we have to update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - get the click event to listen on all clinks and then modify the chatbox id to include the full link id so you can cross reference like so:

```
<a class="clinks" 
   style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" 
   id="msgr<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" 
   href="javascript:void(0)">
   message
</a>
<div id="chatboxmsgr<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" > </div>

$(".clinks").click(function(){
    $("#chatbox" + this.id).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link's id is not "#msgr", it's "#msgr123" (or whatever `$d['qid']` is).

You can use `$("[id^="msgr"])` to find elements that start with that id.

```js
$('[id^="msgr"]').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/^msgr/, '');
  $("#chatbox" + id).fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='msgr123'>click</div>
<div id='chatbox123' style='display:none;'>chatbox</div>
```

Comment: there is no div for message link

Comment: Doesn't need a div, that was only for the example snippet (updated snippet to remove confusion).   Use `$("[id^="msgr"])` as in the answer text.

Answer (score -1):

```
  $("#msgr"+qid).click(function(){
          $("#chatbox"+qid).fadeIn();
        });
```

Comment: well i have tried that too Not working

Comment: `qid` is undefined